# About quotes in mySQL query

Tags: php, mysql

Code example:

```
$query = "INSERT INTO $table SET 
    category     = '".$_POST['new_dish_category']."', 
    name_of_dish = '".$_POST["new_dish_name"]."',           
    discription  = '".$_POST["new_dish_discription"]."', 
    weight       = '".$_POST["new_dish_weight"]."', 
    price        = '".$_POST["new_dish_price"]."'";
```

Can anyone explain me, why here we put quotes like it is? First and second of them I can undersatnd, but the third and then concatenation - I do not understand.

And the second question: maybe there is a better way? I'm just a beginer and my english is poor, so... :)

Comment: Yes, yes, yes, there is a much better way! Because this is wide open for SQL injection. I'm not sure if you're using [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) or [mysqli](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.php) (PLEASE be using one of those) but look into prepared statements and parameter binding. Basically, as a string, your variables going into your columns need to be quoted, but prepared statements eliminates that need.

Comment: In this query string, you set the content of the string to everything between  the doublequotes ("). This means, that the singlequotes (') will actually be in the string. Which is what you want for the sql to be correct. the sql string that you generate will be something like this: 
`INSERT INTO test_table SET category = 'testcategory1', name_of_dish = 'pizza margarita', ...and so on.

Comment: Should be `'description'`, and weight and price shouldnt need `''` they should be integer/decimal fields

Comment: Never ever parse `$_POST` data directly into an sqlquery [SQLInjection], if you have prepared variables you can do `category     = '{$new_dish_category}',`

Comment: Great thanks for everyone!

Answer (score 0):

It's quite simple.

Have a look at this

```
name_of_dish = '" . $_POST['new_dish_name'] . "',
```

The `'` is set for the mysql parser, so mysql will know, that after `'` comes the string to insert.

The `"` finishes the string for the php variable. But you can remove them because functions and variables are interpreted by php as long as they are written in `""`.

```
$variable_1 = "a test string"; // output: a test string
$variable_2 = "Test string with $variable_1"; // output: Test string with a test string

$variable_3 = 'a second test'; // output: a second test
$variable_4 = 'Test string with $variable_3'; // output: Test string with $variable_3
```